# MongoDB: is it possible to get the second document in an aggregation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to generate an algorithm in mongodb for an activity feed of a social network.

I can easily get the first commentor's name in an aggregation query:

```
group2 = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "commentor" : {
            "$first" : "$commentor"
        }
    }
}
```

However, sometimes, we have posts where the users comment like this on a post:

```
Commentor 1: Simon (Latest Commentor - I replied to Mary's comment)
Commentor 2: Mary (Second-latest Commentor)
```

The first commentor of a certain post is me, so in the activity feed, I cannot go as that will make no sense:

```
Simon commented on Simon's post.
```

I want to get the second commentors name so that it displays:

```
Mary commented on Simon's post.
```

Is there something similar to this that I can do? The below is pseudocode:

```
group2 = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "commentor" : {
            "$second" : "$commentor"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is "commentor" an array?

Comment: well its more like a unwinded array... but I think you have given me an idea on how to solve this. I will just have to use addToSet temporarily and then obtain the second item within the array.